# Select greatest numbered filename

Tags: files, find, wildcards, date, sort

I have a list of dated files as below...

```
filename_20120101.dat
filename_20120102.dat
filename_20120103.dat
```

I need a script which selects the most recent file based on the date in the filename (not the file's date stamp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls(1)` sorts files by name, so `ls | tail -1` should do.

Comment: Or use `-r` for sorting in reverse order: `ls -1r | head -1`

Answer (score 10):

Obligatory zsh answer:

```
echo "The highest-numbered file is" filename_*.dat([-1])
```

This is a glob with the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `[NUM]` to retain only the NUMth match (a negative value counts from the last match). If you have numbers of varying width, add the `n` qualifier to

```
% ls
filename_1.dat filename_12.dat filename_17.dat filename_2.dat filename_8.dat
% echo filename_*.dat([-1])
filename_8.dat
% echo filename_*.dat(n[-1])
filename_17.dat
```

Globbing only happens in a context that looks for a list of words, so if you want to assign the filename to a variable, you need to make it an array which will contain one element:

```
latest=( filename_*.dat([-1]) )
echo "The highest-numbered file is $latest"
```

---

In any shell, you can set the positional arguments to the full list of matches and keep the last one.

```
set_latest () {
  eval "latest=\${$#}"
}
set_latest filename_*.dat
echo "The highest-numbered file is $latest"
```

Keep in mind that this returns the last in alphabetical order, not in numerical order, e.g. `filename_10.dat` is after `filename_09.dat` but before `filename_9.dat`.

Comment: This is a nice solution.  Is there a way to return the actual number rather than the full file name?  `echo $latest` would return `17` rather than `filename_17.dat`?

Comment: @agf1997 Use string manipulation to extract the number. For example `number=${latest%.*}; number=${number#"${number%[!0-9]*}"?};`

Answer (score 3):

1-liner:

```bash
# for numerical order 
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.dat' -print | sort -rV | head -n1

# for alphabetical order
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.dat' -print | sort -r | head -n1
```

Note: You can use `ls` instead of `find`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `sort -V`. But (1) In situations like this, it is infinitesimally more efficient to sort so that the desired answer comes first, and then use `head`.  (2) Your “alphabetical” answer will not work in general.  `find` does not sort its output.  If you are testing this in WSL or Cygwin, you are seeing the influence of the underlying Windows.  (3) ```ls | tail -n1``` was already given as an answer

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' , thank you. I updated this answer, so it uses `head` and there is less computation on seeking after sort (1); added sorting for alphabetical solution (2);

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames are completely numerical, this needs to be piped through sort first, as ls will sort the files alphabetically, and 10 will occur before 9

```
$ touch {1..10)
$ ls | tail -1
> 9

$ ls | sort -n | tail -1
> 10
```