# Find latest folder/file version and remove - no time stamp data

Tags: bash, awk, sed, rename

I have data recovered from a backup and the data recovered has multiple versions of the same folders/files.  The folders/files have been named with _000 _001 _002 etc on the files and folders. All modified time stamps are the same. So the folders/fileslook like this

```
[PATH  ~/Folder/9] (VERSION 1) EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_000] (VERSION 2) EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_001] (VERSION 3) Data is in this last one  

FILEA.TXT (VERSION 1) remove/delete this one  
FILEA_000.TXT (VERSION 2) remove/delete this one  
FILEA_001.TXT (VERSION 3) remove/delete this one  
FILEA_002.TXT (VERSION 4) I need to keep this one and then rename  

FILEB.TXT (VERSION 1) remove/delete this one  
FILEB_000.TXT (VERSION 2) I need to keep this one and then rename
```

Some of these folders go 6+ deep.  The pattern I have found is that the last file or folder version for each folder/file is the good one and the folders that are unwanted are empty.  The bad thing is not all files/folders have the same number of versions.  So just because FILEA.TXT has 4 versions (FILEA.TXT to FILEA_002.TXT) FILEB.TXT only has 2 versions (FILEB.TXT & FILEB_000.TXT). So I can't search all files with `_002` and move or delete.  I was easily able to delete all the unwanted empty folders with bash (`find . -type d -empty -delete`) which takes care of part of my problem on the folders except for renaming back.

I need to remove all the files that are unwanted and THEN remove the version numbers on folders/files so my software can correctly import the recovered data.  Here is a example of a path and the files and folders in the path.

```
[PATH  ~/Folder/9] EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_000] EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_001] Data is in this last one  

[PATH  ~/Folder/9_001/62BF7CA1] EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_001/62BF7CA1_000] EMPTY - and can be deleted  
[PATH  ~/Folder/9_001/62BF7CA1_001] Data is in the last one  

[ FOLDERS/FILES IN "~/Folder/9_001/62BF7CA1_001" ]  

Archive - unwanted deleted it  
Archive_000 - unwanted deleted it  
Archive_001 - unwanted deleted it  
Archive_002 - unwanted deleted it  
Archive_003 - keep  
Documents - unwanted deleted it  
Documents_000 - keep
FolderX - unwanted deleted it  
FolderX_000 - unwanted deleted it  
FolderX_001 - unwanted deleted it  
FolderX_002 - keep
62BF7CA1.PDF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_000.PDF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_001.PDF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_002.PDF - keep  
62BF7CA1.TXT- keep
62BF7CA1.DOC - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_000.DOC - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_001.DOC - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_002.DOC - keep  
62BF7CA1.QIF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_000.QIF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_001.QIF - unwanted deleted it  
62BF7CA1_002.QIF - keep
```

The files and folders in this path to keep would be

```
Archive_003  
Documents_000  
FolderX_002  
62BF7CA1_002.PDF  
62BF7CA1.TXT  
62BF7CA1_002.DOC  
62BF7CA1_002.QIF
```

... and then I need to drop any _000 _001 _002 etc if it exist on each file folder

```
Archive  
Documents  
FolderX  
62BF7CA1.PDF  
62BF7CA1.TXT  
62BF7CA1.DOC  
62BF7CA1.QIF
```

Probably easy with things like sed and pipes but I have no idea.

Comment: Why `FILEB_000.TXT` is deleted that there is no `FILEB_001.TXT` while `Documents_000` is not deleted. What is the logic then? and are you on linux machine or windows? If you are on Windows you should ask on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Thanks for catching that it was a type-o.  The data is from Windows but I am on a linux machine to manipulate the data into the form I need

Comment: Your case is difficult to achieve with an easy solution, please take a look here for start [Select greatest numbered filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66796/select-greatest-numbered-filename)

Comment: So, are all the excess directories empty?  Or might you have to deal with `Archive_001/FileA_001.txt`, `Archive_001/FileA_002.txt`, `Archive_002/FileA_001.txt` and `Archive_002/FileA_002.txt`?

Comment: Your question is not clear kindly post with input and excepted output what i have undestood and done below is code from my end  @praveen_2 j1]# for i in Archive Documents EF PDF TXT DOC QIF ; do sed -n "/$i/p" l.txt | tail -1; done
Archive_003
Documents_000
EF_002
62BF7CA1_002.PDF
62BF7CA1.TXT
62BF7CA1_002.DOC
62BF7CA1_002.QIF
You have new mail in

Comment: -- G-Man -- I was easily able to delete all the unwanted empty folders with bash (find . -type d -empty -delete) which takes care of part of my problem on the folders except for renaming back.  So Yes all are empty and I already handled that part.

Comment: @αғsнιη Cygwin is on topic here

Comment: @wade812: (1) Thanks for answering my question. (2) I saw your response (and your more recent comment) only because I happened to come back and look. To notify somebody when you write a comment to them, use @ followed by their name; e.g., @G-Man. (3) If you want to say that all your files have names including a **`.`**, then *say so*. We don’t want to assume that all your files have names including a **`.`** just because you don’t show any examples that don’t. (4) If you want to clean up this question, how about removing the Windows-convention pathnames (e.g., ```C:\Folder\...```)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate across all files. Find the ones that also match with the `_nnn` component. Identify the last one and delete the others.

If you need this to apply across a tree of folders one option is to put this into a script and call the script from a `find -type d -exec` construct.

```
for file in *.*
do
    [[ -d "$file" || $file =~ _[[:digit:]]{3}\. ]] && continue
    echo -n "Considering $file: " >&2

    extn="${file/*.}"
    versions=("$file")
    keep="$file"

    # Look at matching files
    for version in "${file%.$extn}"_???."$extn"
    do
        [[ -f "$version" ]] || continue

        # Save every one. Identify the current last
        versions+=("$version")
        keep="$version"
        echo -n "$version " >&2
    done
    echo "==> keep $keep" >&2

    # Delete them all except the last
    for version in "${versions[@]}"
    do
        [[ "$version" != "$keep" ]] && echo rm -f -- "$version"
    done
    [[ "$keep" != "$file" ]] && echo mv -f -- "$keep" "$file"
done
```

Remove the `echo` statements preceding the `rm -f -- "$version"` and the `mv -f -- "$keep" "$file"` when you're comfortable it's deleting the files you want deleted and keeping the ones you want kept.

Comment: Thank you for the response Roaima.  I ran the for loop and it produced the output I am looking for.  Appreciate it.  Sorry I have to ask but how would I put this into a script and call the script from a find -type d -exec construct?  

like this?  

#!/bin/bash  
find -type -d -exec myscript {} \;

Comment: (1) `*.*` expands to a list of filenames *that contain* **`.`**.  The question mentions `Archive`, `Documents`, and `EF`.  Yes, the first two are probably directories, but I don’t know what `EF` is, and `*.*` will ignore it.  (Of course, by definition, filenames with no **`.`** have no extension, so you would need slightly different code to handle them.)  (2) You could use `globstar` to search a directory tree.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) This will `mv 62bf7ca1_002.doc 62bf7ca1.doc` without first doing `rm 62bf7ca1.doc`.  This will cause problems if `62bf7ca1.doc` is read-only.  (I would suggest initializing `versions=("$file")`, so the unnumbered version gets deleted if there are other versions.  Doing ```mv -f``` is another option.) (4) You should probably use **`--`** with `rm` and `mv` to protect against filenames beginning with **`-`**.

Comment: -- G-Man -- I updated the question to make it clear what are folders and what are files.  Yes 'EF' was a folder but I changed it to 'FolderX' to make it more clear.  Again don't have to worry about Folder finding and renaming as I have already taken care of that.  Just concerned with files.   Thank you for following up with me. Appreciate it!  Still need to understand how to call 'roaima' code from a contruct. :-)

Comment: @G-Man all the examples dictated files with an extension. Those are what I have matched. I think I've fixed the remainder of your suggestions (at least one slipped through my rewrite of prototype code). Thanks