# Remove all but latest version - no timestamp

Tags: bash, rm

I have a large collection of files that look like this:

```
Some Name da-1234567-1.py
Some Name da-1234567-2.py
Some Name da-1234567-4.py
Other Name di-5678912-3.py
Other Name di-5678912-4.py
Other Name di-5678912-5.py
```

I would like to remove all versions and only keep:

```
Some Name da-1234567-4.py
Other Name di-5678912-5.py
```

I realise my question is similar to [Find latest folder/file version and remove - no time stamp data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421348/find-latest-folder-file-version-and-remove-no-time-stamp-data) . However its answer does not work for me and my knowledge of bash and/or regular expression is insufficient to change the solution to cater my needs. Unfortunately I do not have the reputation score to comment thus I do not see another option than to post a new question.

I tried the following from above question:

```
for file in *.*
do
  [[ -d "$file" || $file =~ _[[:digit:]]{3}\. ]] && continue
  echo -n "Considering $file: " >&2

  extn="${file/*.}"
  versions=("$file")
  keep="$file"

  # Look at matching files
  for version in "${file%.$extn}"_???."$extn"
  do
      [[ -f "$version" ]] || continue

      # Save every one. Identify the current last
      versions+=("$version")
      keep="$version"
      echo -n "$version " >&2
  done
  echo "==> keep $keep" >&2

  # Delete them all except the last
  for version in "${versions[@]}"
  do
      [[ "$version" != "$keep" ]] && echo rm -f -- "$version"
  done
  [[ "$keep" != "$file" ]] && echo mv -f -- "$keep" "$file"
done
```

I realise that it probably goes wrong in this part:
     `$file =~ _[[:digit:]]{3}\.`, since opposed to the above question my file ending is -n and not _nnn, but I do not see how to fix it.

Comment: Are all your files ending in `-`, a single digit, `.py`? If so just change the `_` to a `-`, the `3` to a `1` and you should be good to go. You could also delete the `{3}` part because `1` is default.

Comment: Yes they are all the same format. That was my first guess before asking this question, without success unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software tools one-liner, using `ls -v` and `sort -V` which sort by version number:

```
{ ls -Qrv *.py |rev | uniq -f 1 | rev; ls -Q *.py; } | sort -V | uniq -u | xargs rm
```

Using `uniq -f 1` depends on the file naming format being consistent -- the surrounding `rev`s are needed because `-f` has no other way of ignoring the last field.

Comment: Thanks so much, that solved it! There is a small typo though: there should be a space behind the {

Comment: Note that while `ls -Q` (a GNU extension like `rev`, `uniq -f`, `sort -V`) would work with the OP's sample, it is generally not compatible with the format expected by `xargs`. It wouldn't work properly with file names that contain double quotes, backslashes or control characters for instance.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
# all *.<number>.py files in "n"umerical order
files=(*-<->.py(n))

# associative array whose key is the part before the last "-"
typeset -A latest
for f ($files) latest[${f%-*}]=$f

# plain array with the values of the associative array
keep=($latest)

# array subtraction:
echo rm -- ${files:|keep}
```

(remove `echo` if happy).

That makes no assumption on what characters the rest of the file names may contain. With `bash` (or `zsh` or `ksh`) and GNU tools:

```
xargs -r0a <(printf '%s\0' *-*.py |
  grep -zEe '-[[:digit:]]+\.py$' |
  sort -zrV |
  awk -vRS='\0' -vORS='\0' '
    {key = $0; sub(/-[^-]*$/, "", key)}
    seen[key]++') echo rm --
```