# Rsync only file with highest number in name

Tags: bash, rsync

I have many files all in a similar format: `filename_<number>.ext` And actually on the same level also folders with the name `<number>`. I want to copy only the file and folder that have the highest number, but I don't know how to go about that.

I was thinking maybe I can uses zsh like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66996/533685): `filename_*.ext([-1])` but I'm actually using rsync's include and exclude filters and then I don't think passing this in an include filter will work. (I actually tried and how I tried it, it didn't work)

My file structure

```
SomeFolder
-> DataFrom1
   -> output
      -> filename_0.ext
         filename_1.ext
         filename_2.ext
         0
         -> filename_0_0.ext
            filename_0_1.ext
         1
         -> filename_1_0.ext
            filename_1_1.ext
         2
         -> filename_2_0.ext
            filename_2_1.ext
   DataFrom2
   -> output
      -> filename_0.ext
         filename_4.ext
         filename_8.ext
         0
         -> filename_0_0.ext
            filename_0_1.ext
         4
         -> filename_4_0.ext
            filename_4_1.ext
         8
         -> filename_8_0.ext
            filename_8_1.ext
```

So I want to copy `DataFrom1/output/filename_2.ext`, `DataFrom1/output/2/*`, `DataFrom2/output/filename_8.ext` and `DataFrom2/output/8/*` from `SomeFolder` to `DestinationFolder` (keeping the same hierarchy)

Comment: I think you are better off by first creating the list with files and directories that should be transferred, then use `rsync  --files-from=LISTFILE`.